# Laptop gives infinite keyboard input for any Linux distro

Tags: linux, drivers, keyboard, hardware, hp

Im running an HP ENVY 15-J011DX and I have a problem with input: as soon as I press a key on the (shift z x c v) bottom row the driver spits out infinite of that character, and I can't stop it with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>..I know its not the hardware because this device dual boots with Windows and has no problems in Windows. Is there something I can do to try and replace the driver? It started breaking sometime last year on a Debian update (it used to work on Debian fine). Then I rolled to Kali and then Arch, both with the same result.

Has anyone ever encountered similar issues? Its a shame because its a decent [machine](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HP_Envy_15).

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: It seems extremely unlikely to me that the issue would not be hardware related, even if the bug doesn't appear on Windows.  I would suspect the keyboard needs to be replaced.

Comment: Interesting.  So the keyboard doesn't work with recent *Kali*, *Arch*, and *Debian*.   Start from an older bootCD if you have any lying around -- if last year's *Debian* worked, try that.  Or some other non-*Linux* non-*Windows* OS.  Assuming any of those work, we can safely assume it's a *Linux* driver bug.

Comment: @agc OpenBSD may be a good place to start (again). I suppose another option is to look through the driver repos and try and pick an old one that used to work, assuming its different than the current.